# Looking for an alternative to serializing data in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking for a method to switch from serializing data (which I originally did using Mvc Futures) and passing it around my controller actions to something that does not use serialize. My previous implementation was for a wizard that passed data from action to action until it was submitted and the data was saved. However, I am unable to use serialization in a new project and am looking for an alternative.

Here is an example of what I did in my controller:

```
private MyViewModel myViewModel;
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var serialized = Request.Form["myViewModel"];
    if (serialized != null) //Form was posted containing serialized data
    {
        myViewModel = (MyViewModel)new MvcSerializer()
            .Deserialize(serialized, SerializationMode.Signed);

            TryUpdateModel(myViewModel);
    }
    else
        myViewModel= (MyViewModel)TempData["myViewModel"] ?? new MyViewModel();
        TempData.Keep();
}
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
        TempData["myViewModel"] = myViewModel;
}
```

Then in some actions:

```
// STEP 1:
public ActionResult Step1()
{
    return View(myViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Step1")]
public ActionResult Step1POST(string nextButton)
{
    if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("Step2");
    return View(myViewModel);
}


// STEP 2:
[Themed]
public ActionResult Step2()
{
    return View(myViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Step2")]
public ActionResult Step2POST(string backButton, string nextButton)
{
    if (backButton != null)
        return RedirectToAction("Step1");
    else if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("Step3");
    return View(myViewModel);
}
```

My view would contain this inside the @Html.BeginForm block:

```
@Html.Hidden("myViewModel", 
    new MvcSerializer().Serialize(Model, SerializationMode.Signed))
```

My first thought is that I have no other alternative (other than maybe jQuery, which I also cannot use right now). In this scenario I have to figure out how to use TempData in each ActionResult, which will get messy if I have 10 or so inputs in each view.

So my question would probably be two-fold:

1. Is there a clean alternative to using serialize in this manner?
2. If there is no clean alternative and I am forced to do it in each
   ActionResult, I am not sure of how to do so if, for example, I kept
   it to one input view and one submit/confirm view and just wanted to
   pass two values to the "Submit" step (not shown above), such as
   FirstName an EMail. How might I do that using TempData?

Thanks.