# Does using TempData.Keep() save all prior TempData if using multiple Actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20055350/624479) yesterday.

I believe I have found the answer in using TempData. My new question is whether or not stringing along TempData through actions (as in wizard steps) will "keep" all the prior TempData or if I have to keep redeclaring to "keep" it in each action.

So, if TempData Step1 has fields 1, 2 and 3, and then Step2 has fields 4, 5 and 6, will 1 through 6 be kept in Step3 thusly:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step1 (Step1Model model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TempData["Step1"] = model;
        return RedirectToAction("Step2")
    }
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Step2 (Step2Model model)
{
    Step1Model step1 = (Step1Model)TempData["Step1"]
    if (step1 == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Step1")
    }
    TempData.Keep("Step1")
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TempData["Step2"] = model;
        return RedirectToAction("Step3")
    }
    return View(model);
}
public ActionResult Step3()
{
    TempData.Keep() // is this keeping Step1 and Step2?
    return View();
}
```

The above is oversimplified. Ultimately, I may have 6 or 7 steps and want to know if Step3 had to redeclare the use of Step1 and Step2 as I did in Step2 (i.e.: in a new Step3, would I have to write `Step1Model step1...;` and `Step2Model step2...;`?

Comment: @Satpal So then don't "keep" a specific step, just keep calling `TempData.Keep()` in each Action to save all prior TempData action steps?

Comment: Yes, Just call `TempData.Keep()` before redirection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TempData items are only tagged for removal after they are read. When a key is marked for retention, the key is retained for the next request. As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728654%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) `TempData.Keep()` Marks all keys in the dictionary for retention.

Just call `TempData.Keep()` before redirection

Comment: What if I don't EVER read the TempData, will it expire by itself? Or will it kept in server memory forever until server restart?

Comment: @RosdiKasim, Comments are not a place to ask new question. However lets focus on your question `will it expire by itself?`. Answer is `Yes`

Comment: I think its not a bad place either .. comments are for discussions to clear concepts

Comment: @UsmanY, Only if you are original poster of Question or question was active not after months later